# SQL JOIN, return data from 4 tables?

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join

I have this query that works atm:

```
SELECT
    u.UserName, v.registration, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(4), i.starttime, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), i.starttime, 120) as StartTime , 
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfInspections, 
    COUNT(id.id) AS NumberOfDefects
FROM
    INSPECTIONS i
join 
    [user] u on i.DRIVERID = u.UserID 
join 
    Vehicle v on i.VEHICLEID = v.VehicleID 
left outer join 
    INSPECTIONDEFECTS id on id.inspectionid = i.id
WHERE 
    i.COMPANYID = 3 
    AND i.STARTTIME > '01-jan-2014' 
GROUP BY 
    u.UserName, v.registration, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(4), i.starttime, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), i.starttime, 120)
ORDER BY 
    u.UserName, v.registration
```

But I don't want to have the counts in it, is there a way to remove them and have it still work? Whenever I do the query won't work anymore.

Comment: If you don't want the count, remove the COUNT(*) from your query.

Comment: just removing it doesnt work, you need an aggregate or a group by before that part and group by doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `group by` portion of the query as well in order to get this query work without `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `COUNT` and also the `GROUP BY` try this query i hope it will work

```
    SELECT u.UserName, v.registration, CONVERT(CHAR(4), 
    i.starttime, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), i.starttime, 120) AS StartTime, (id.id) AS NumberOfDefects
    FROM INSPECTIONS i
    JOIN [user] u on i.DRIVERID = u.UserID 
    JOIN Vehicle v on i.VEHICLEID = v.VehicleID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INSPECTIONDEFECTS id on id.inspectionid = i.id
    where i.COMPANYID = 3 and i.STARTTIME > '01-jan-2014' 
    order by u.UserName, v.registration
```